# Java code issue: Capping an amount

Tags: java, if-statement

I am a beginner to java programming and have an issue with figuring out how to cap an amount in my code.

I have an issue with my code which is made up of if-else if statements, this is more a question of how to cap the maximum amount of prize money. I want my maximum amount of prize money to be 300 dollars. I do not want any of the contestants to receive more than this. The equation that determines this is

prize= (60-mins4)*10/2;

this determines based on the contestants time the amount of cash they receive. The issue is if they exceed 300 dollars, I want to be able to have the system automatically return it to 300. I am asking what method that I can use to do this or if there is a way to cap the amount?

Comment: java or javascript?

Comment: Use `math.min` e.g. `math.min(300,(60-mins4)*10/2)`

Comment: Thank you! it is java, sorry I fixed the flag.

Comment: Seems you learned already about `if` statements. This would be a typical application of an `if`: if the price is higher than 300 set it to 300.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest, you have two common routes: Use a math utility, or use a IF-THEN-ELSE test.

## `if-then-else`

Example using if-then-else.

```
int input = … ;  
int calculation = runMyCalculation( input ) ; 
int result ;
if( calculation > 300 ) {  // If over the cap, override calculated amount to use the maximum, the cap amount of 300. 
    result = 300 ;  // Limit specified by Marie Leclerc on 2018-01-23 in email, and verified in conversation. --Basil Bourque
} else {  // Else not over the cap, so use result of calculation.
    result = calculation ;
}
```

Note the comments. I actually do write such comments in all my production code, spelling out in natural human language (English for me) the logic and business rules behind my if-then-else statement. Writing these comments clarifies my thinking in the moment, and helps to verify I got the logic correct. The comments do the same for people reviewing my code. Later those comments are invaluable when debugging, especially if addressing some urgent fix in the middle of the night. Eventually they become important documentation for the programmer inheriting this code.

More brief to assign the initial calculation to `result`.

```
int input = … ;
int calculation = runMyCalculation( input ) ; // Run your calculation code.
int result = calculation ;
if( result >= 300 ) {
    result = 300 ;  // Override the first assigned value with the cap amount, 300.
}
```

If going with that briefer version, we do not really need two separate variables.

```
int input = … ;
int result = runMyCalculation( input ) ; // Run your calculation code.
if( result >= 300 ) {
    result = 300 ;  // Override the calculated value with the cap amount, 300.
}
```

Better to declare the cap amount as a named [constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(computer_programming)) rather than scattering a [“magic” number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) about.

```
static final int CAP_AMOUNT = 300 ;  // Use `static final` if this number is fixed at runtime, never varying. 
…
int input = … ;
int result = runMyCalculation( input ) ; // Run your calculation code.
if( result >= myClass.CAP_AMOUNT ) {
    result = myClass.CAP_AMOUNT ;  // Override the calculated value with the cap.
}
```

You can shorten this further by using a [ternary conditional operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html), shorthand for `if-then-else` statement). The ternary operator is entirely optional. Use only where it makes your code *more* readable, not less. In some conventional compiled languages the ternary might by the tiniest bit faster, but I expect any JVM with a [runtime optimizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot) would be as fast either with the ternary or without the if-then-else.

```
static final int CAP_AMOUNT = 300 ;  // Use `static final` if this number is fixed at runtime, never varying. 
…
int input = … ;
int result = … ; // Run your calculation code.
result = ( result > myClass.CAP_AMOUNT ) ? myClass.CAP_AMOUNT : result ;  // Shorthand version of if-then-else.
```

## `Math` utility class

The [`Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class offers handy utilities. One of those is the `min` method where you pass a pair of numbers. You get back whichever is smaller.

```
int result = Math.min( runMyCalculation( input ) , myClass.CAP_AMOUNT ) ;  // Return whichever is smaller.
```

Personally, I would go with this approach. This code is brief while still being clear as to my intentions.

But I would break out the call to calculation separately. Having the separate `calculation` variable facilitates [debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging) and [logging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_file).

```
int calculation = runMyCalculation( input ) ;  // Run your calculation code.
int result = Math.min( calculation , myClass.CAP_AMOUNT ) ;  // Return whichever is smaller.
```

## Validate input

Lastly, you could validate the input, rejecting certain values to control the output. But that was not the thrust of your Question I suspect.